# Is there any way to fetch data into Tabulator with POST method?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, tabulator

I am using Tabulator 4.6, and I have an API with POST method, and I want to fetch tabulator data through a POST request, not GET.

In my org.js is like:

```js
var ajaxConfig = {
    mode: "no-cors",
    method: "POST", //set request type to Position
    headers: {
        "Content-type": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
    },
var ajaxParams = { key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};
var ajaxURL = "https://rest.com/api/listrobot";

function queryRealm(url, config, params) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxURL,
            success: function (data) {
                //do some async data retrieval then pass the array of row data back into Tabulator
                //resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                //if there is an error call this function and pass the error message or object into it
                reject(error);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

My backend API URL "https://rest.com/api/listrobot" is returning JSON data, and I have tried with postman also.

In `org.js(tabulator)`, when I tried using the GET method to fetch data, it works well when I changed it to POST accordingly API also it is not working.

```php
Route::post('/listrobot',[OrgrobotController::class,'ReadRobot'])->name('list_robot');
```

I tried this URL with org.js(tabulator) throws *Ajax load error statusText: "Method Not Allowed"*

Comment: I do not have knowledge about tabulator but if you want to make a POST request than you must add following line  ```type: "POST"``` in ```$.ajax```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the request method to POST using the `ajaxConfig` option

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://www.getmydata.com/now", //ajax URL
    ajaxConfig:"POST", //ajax HTTP request type
});
```